# Create a database file in external storage in android 11 using room database

Tags: android, android-room, android-external-storage, android-11, scoped-storage

I have worked in android app, which is store the data in **local database** whenever internet is not available,
The local database is placed in external storage inside the folder of the mobile phone, But now in android 11
they asked to use scoped storage.

**Method1:**
I used the scoped storage and upload the apk in playstore but they rejected the app. Because of full access.

**Method2:**
Create the app folder in public directory such as document or download. We can achieve to create and upload
in playstore successfully. But Sometimes user uninstall the previous app and update the new version of the app.
In that time new version of the app cannot access the local db..

I'm using **room database** and I create an object like this

```
public static final String A11_DB_PATH = 
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/appName/database/";

INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(application, AppDatabase.class, A11_DB_PATH + DB_NAME)
           .allowMainThreadQueries()
           .openHelperFactory(factory)
           .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
           .build();
```

Comment: `The local database is placed in external storage inside the folder of the mobile phone` ? Where would that be? You better mention full path

Comment: mnt\sdcard\document\appname\appDatabase.db

Comment: `...\document\..` ? Who created that `document` directory? It's not on my devices.

Comment: It is a public storage directory, no one create the directory as document, I have created the folder inside the document directory.

Comment: Well as said before: my devices dont have a public `document` directory.

Comment: @blackapps could u pls share ur mailid ?